# how to remove duplicate entries from many to many relation using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables look like this. my op and country is having many to many relationships with each other.

```
OP
id, name,.....

op_country
id, op_id, country_id

country
id, name, ...

my op_country filled like below

id  op_id   country_id
1     1        1
2     1        2
3     2        2
4     2        3
5     3        3
6     3        3
7     1        1
```

I want to remove my duplicate entries from op_country. Here I want to remove rows 6 and 7 since we already have rows with such values.

How can I do that.

Comment: What's your mysql version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE t1
FROM op_country t1
JOIN op_country t2 USING (op_id, country_id)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=247ebc5870a6ab10b64076ffb375797f

Comment: your query executes fine but does not update the table, means it does not remove the duplicates.

Comment: @TalibDaryabi Fiddle contradicts your words and shows that duplicated rows are removed.

Comment: I see the updates there, but can't see it in my database, I will check my database.

Comment: @TalibDaryabi Edit the fiddle, add **real** table structure and some sample data then provide the link. Will look...

Comment: updated the fiddle, you can check, the link is:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7a7727a9ac096a523773a3480386aff

Comment: @TalibDaryabi What rows do you need to be removed? I do **not** see the rows pairs with the same `(op_id, country_id)` in your data.

Comment: rows number 32 should be deleted as it is duplicated in the table.

Comment: @TalibDaryabi o_O  What row does the row 32 interfere?

Comment: row 32 is the same with row 31, 32 is duplicate of 31. I want to removes rows which is duplicate to any other row in the table.

Comment: @TalibDaryabi Do you really think that 256 and 265 are equal?

Comment: OMG, my mistake , sorry. I accepted and voted your answer

Comment: @TalibDaryabi Do not work so hard, rest sometimes... :)

Comment: yeah, I really feel tired. Thank you so much. having guys like you in the community makes me feel proud. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete entries for which exists a sibling with a lower ID:

```
delete from op_country
where exists
(
  select null
  from (select * from op_country) op2
  where op2.op_id = op_country.op_id
  and op2.country_id = op_country.country_id
  and op2.id < op_country.id
);
```

The `from (select * from op_country)` is necessary instead of a mere `from op_country` due to some weird restriction in MySQL updates.

Comment: please have a look to this Fiddle, I have entered the last row as a duplicate one, it is just a sample, there might be lots of duplicate in the table. I want to remove those duplicates   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7a7727a9ac096a523773a3480386aff